# Radix Sort - O(n) Time

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, time-complexity, radix-sort

I heard that if we are sorting `n` numbers and that the numbers being sorted were converted to base n, then radix sort could be performed in O(n) time.

Have I got this right?

If so, how exactly is this achieved. If we are dealing with 5 numbers and we convert them all to base 5, we can separate the digits into 5 buckets (0, 1, 2, 3, 4).

Even if the numbers we were dealing with had only 7 digits max, wouldn't you still have to cycle through at least 7 * 5 times..? This doesn't seem right.. however.

Sorry, kind of confused about this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm, should this be asked on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Radix sort works by picking some number base b, writing all the numbers in the input in base b, then sorting the numbers one digit at a time. In this answer, I'll focus on least-significant digit radix sort, in which we sort everything by the least-significant digit, then the second-least-significant digit, etc.

Each time we sort the numbers by some digit, we have to do O(n) work to distribute the elements across all the buckets, then O(n + b) work to iterate across the buckets and obtain the elements in sorted order. Therefore, the runtime for one round of radix sort is O(n + b).

The number of rounds of radix sort depends on the number of digits in each of the numbers. If you write numbers in base b, there will be O(log<sub>b</sub> M) base-b digits in the number M. If we let M denote the maximum number in the input array, the number of rounds of radix sort will then be O(log<sub>b</sub> M). Therefore, the asymptotic runtime of radix sort is

> O(n + b) · O(log<sub>b</sub> M) = O((n + b) log<sub>b</sub> M).

In a typical binary radix sort, you'd pick b = 2 and get a runtime of O(n log M). However, you can choose b to be any value you'd like. If you pick a larger value of b, then there will be fewer base-b digits in each of the numbers (as an example, write a number in base-10 and then in base-16; you'll usually need fewer digits in base-16). In your original question, you asked

> Even if the numbers we were dealing with had only 7 digits max, wouldn't you still have to cycle through at least 7 * 5 times?

The answer is "not necessarily." If you do a base-10 radix sort with 7-digit numbers, then yes, you'd have to cycle 7 times. However, if you used a base-100 radix sort, you'd only need to cycle 4 times.

Your other question was about using base-n for the radix sort. If we choose the base we use to be the number n, then we get that the runtime is

> O((n + n) log<sub>n</sub> M) = O(n log<sub>n</sub> M) = O(n log M / log n)

(This uses the change-of-basis formula for logarithms to rewrite log<sub>n</sub> M = log M / log n).

This is *not* O(n), nor should you expect it to be. Think of it this way - radix sort's runtime depends on the length of the strings being sorted. If you sort a small number of extremely long numbers, the runtime is bound to be greater than the time to sort a small number of small numbers simply because you have to actually read the digits of the large number. The trick of using base n is simply a technique for speeding up the algorithm asymptotically.

Hope this helps!